# Is there a workaround for using the CSS Calc property on Safari Mobile?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

I have a bootstrap site that I have used the `Calc` css function. I understand that it is not supported by Safari Mobile. Is there a popular workaround? I couldn't find much when I searched the site.

```
        left: calc(50% + 5px);
        left: -moz-calc(50% + 5px);
        left: -webkit-calc(50% + 5px);
```

-

```
        width: calc(100% - 1em);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 1em);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 1em);
```

Comment: Looks like it's supported to me - http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: _“Is there a popular workaround?”_ – depends on what you are trying to achieve here, and how the rest of your layout is set up. // The `left` stuff could probably be solved by just using a pure percentage value, plus a little margin to move the element from _that_ position. And for the `width`, maybe `box-sizing` could solve that issue already(?).